# LinqToSql: cannot insert record

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am learing Linq-to-SQL. I want to add a record, but get an exception on `InsertOnSubmit()`:

> *Can't perform Create, Update, or Delete operations on
>   'Table(GuestbookEntry)' because it has no primary key.*

But my database does have a primary key.

Here is my code:

```
[Table(Name = "GuestbookEntry")]
public class GuestbookEntry
{
    [Column(DbType = "int not null, IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDBGenerated=true")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}

public class GuestbookContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<GuestbookEntry> GuestBookEntries;
    //public Table<Order> Orders;
    public GuestbookContext(string connection) : base(connection) { }
}

...

private GuestbookContext dbGuestbook = new GuestbookContext("GuestBookConnection");

...

dbGuestbook.GuestBookEntries.InsertOnSubmit(entry);
dbGuestbook.SubmitChanges();
```

Could you please tell what is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: u sure that `entry` is populated?

Comment: The primary key is always on table not on database. In order to perform the linq operation you must need to define primary key in the table.

Comment: Yes, entry is populated. Not the Id though as it is supposed to be generated by the database.

Comment: Yes, I meant the table has the primary key.

Comment: Does the table have a primary key in the database? Is the primary key shown in SQL Server Management Studio and can you see it under 'Constraints'?

Comment: Is "GuestBookConnection" just a placeholder, or is that your actual connection string?

Comment: Also, what happens when you insert something into it directly with SQL? (Straight through in Management Studio or a tool like MS)

Comment: It has an actual connection string.

Comment: I can insert a record directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to define a primary key for your table

Comment: It does have a primary key. It was the first thing I made sure.

Comment: is it an identity primary key? Maybe you aren't setting it before insert is called

Comment: Yes, it is identity primary key.

Comment: I think maybe you need to pull the isPrimaryKey out of the dbType="" section. I've moved to Entity Framework since linqtoSql's retired but I think that's it's own deal.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx

Comment: I wonder if that is because the Id has a 0 value. Though I changed it to 1 in debug mode, but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you check out that link? I think the syntax around setting the primary key column is off slightly.

Comment: When I did this:         [Column(Storage = "Id", DbType = "Int NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
, I received "Bad Storage Property", and when I removed Storage, I got the original error.

Comment: I don't see the IsPrimaryKey setting there, we'd want something like this: 

[Column(DbType = "int not null", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDBGenerated=true)]

Comment: This worked! I went through  dbGuestbook.GuestBookEntries.InsertOnSubmit(entry); though I got another exception on SubmitChanges(): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)... The same server works with other applications...

Answer (score 0):

When I learned LINQ-to-SQL, the simplest approach for me to follow was to use the LINQ-to-SQL designer exclusively, rather than trying to manually code the data model. This way, I only had to make sure the database schema was set up exactly the way I wanted it. Once I did that, it was just a matter of following these steps:

1. Create a data connection in Server Explorer to your database.
2. Create a new LINQ-to-SQL Classes item (**Add... | Data | LINQ to SQL Classes** from the Solution Explorer context menu. Name it *GuestBook.dbml*.
3. Drag the table(s) from the data connection to the designer. I'm assuming one of your tables is named *GuestBookEntry*.

Then, in your code, to perform an INSERT:

```
using (GuestBookContext dc = new GuestBookContext())
{
    GuestBookEntry entry = new GuestBookEntry();
    ...
    (populate required fields, BUT DON'T TOUCH THE PRIMARY KEY FIELD)
    ...
    dc.GuestBookEntries.InsertOnSubmit(entry);
    dc.GuestBookEntries.SubmitChanges();
}
```